# My navigator is now showing all my files? Using Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, finder

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and today I noticed something strange. I noticed that my navigator is not showing my App Delegate among other files... When I look at the directory in my finder, the files are there but don't show up in my navigator in Xcode, any ideas as to why this could be happening?

I have searched online but can't find someone with a similar problem..

**This is what i see in my navigator:**

[image]

**This is what I see in my finder:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've typed an "n" into the search bar at the bottom of the navigator. Remove that to un-filter all of your files.